# Polymorphism with different methods in derived classes

Tags: c++, class, oop, polymorphism

While trying to learn polymorphism I am confused about one thing. Consider the following situation:

There exists a base class `Shape` and the derived classes `Circle` and `Square`. With polymorphism I can implement the method `get_area` as virtual function in the base class and implement individual versions of this funtion in the derives classes `Circle` and `Square`.

```
class Shape
{
  public:
    Shape(){}
    virtual int get_area() = 0;
};

class Square: public Shape
{
  public:
    Square(int width, int height)
    {
       // stuff
    }
    int get_area()
    { 
       return width*height; 
    }
};

class Circle: public Shape
{
  public:
    Circle(int radius)
    {
       // stuff
    }
    int get_area()
    { 
       return pi*radius*radius; 
    }
};

int main () 
{
  Shape *circle= new Circle(3);
  Shape *square= new Square(4,5);

  return 0;
}
```

But what if I need to implement a individual method in one of the derived classes, for example `get_radius`. I get error-messsages from the compiler, if this method is not implmeneted as virtual function in the base class. But If I do this, I also have to implement the method `get_radius` in the derived class `Square` and this does not make any sense, because a square does not have a radius.

Is there a better way to cope with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You can most definitely add a `get_radius` method to `Circle` only. Can you please share the problematic code and the error you're getting?

Comment: error C2039: 'get_radius': Is not a member of 'Shape'

Comment: That's useless without the code the code that error. Also, even though I can guess what it means, it would be much more useful in English.

Comment: You *can* have different non virtual functions in your derived class, however you *can't* call them from a base class pointer.

Comment: But I use polymorphism because the ability to use a base class pointer for many different derived class objects... Otherwise I would have to thread all classes (`Cricle`, `Square` etc.) as totally different objects. But this would end in really confusing and bad code.

Comment: Consider the case where you have `Shape* sp = new Square();`, calling `sp->get_radius();` wouldn't work as the function isn't polymorphic, hence why this rule exists

Comment: If you have a `Shape`, you don't know whether it's a `Circle`, a `Triangle` or a `Square`. Why do you think you can call `get_radius` on it? If you know you have a `Circle`, you most definitely can call `get_radius`, you just need to use the correct type: `Circle* circle = ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write

```
Shape *circle=new Circle(4,5);
```

and then you try to use this reference to call the `get_radius()` method

```
circle->get_radius();
```

an error occurs, if you didn't declare a get_radius method, virtual or concrete, in the Shape class. The error occurs because **circle** is not a reference to a Circle, but a reference to a Shape, so the definition of the method cannot be resolved simply because there's no get_radius method defined in Shape. 
On the the other hand, if you declared get_radius in the Shape class, you can (*if it has a concrete implementantion*) call  get_radius for all kind of Shapes and it has no much sense.
So the right way is use a reference to a Circle e.g.

```
Circle *circle=new Circle(4,5);
double r=circle->get_radius();
... //do something with r
```

Answer (score 2):

In general you cannot do what you want without a cast, and that's because runtime polymorphism means exactly that: controlling a class hierarchy via a *common interface*. Your potential `Circle::get_radius()` is not a part of the interface.

One solution which works in case you know your object is a `Circle`: use a downcast

```
Circle* ptrCircle = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(circle);
int radius = 0;
if(ptrCircle) // the cast succeeded
    radius = ptrCircle->get_radius();
```

where `get_radius()` is a member function that's only implemented by `Circle`.

Note: in general the absolute need for a cast signals a bad design, so it's better to spend some time thinking about how to better design your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely add non-virtual member functions to your derived classes without defining them in the base class, however you can't access these from a base class pointer.
ie:

```
//won't work
Shape* shapeP = new Circle();
shapeP ->get_radius(); 
//will work
Circle* circP = new Circle();
circP->get_radius();
```

You can also cast your shape pointer for cases that you know your shape is a circle as mentioned by vsoftco in his answer

Answer (score 1):

There's a chance that I could be misunderstanding you, but it sounds like you're trying to call `circle->get_radius()` in `main` in order to test it. The problem is that `circle` isn't actually a `Circle*` object, it's a `Shape*`. The way derived classes work, you can assign them to variables typed as any of the classes or interfaces they extend/implement – as you've done in your example – because the derived class includes a definition for every member of those base classes/interfaces. The opposite isn't true; as you said, `get_radius()` doesn't make sense for every `Shape`. You're getting errors not because it's missing from `Circle` but because you're trying to get the radius of a random `Shape*` that just happens to use the `Circle` function implementations.

To put it another way, you (as a human) are smart enough to look at the code and see that `circle` is a `Circle*`. The compiler is smart enough to remember "when looking up the functions for `circle`, use those defined by `Circle`", but beyond that it has no idea how that particular `Shape*` instance is different from `square`. As far as it knows, the only things it can do to either of them are what you've told it *every* `Shape` can do.

That's handy in cases where you don't care about what particular `Shape` an object is – all you need is something that can give you an area. In cases where you need to know the radius, or the width and height, or any other property that one `Shape` has but others don't, you need to use a variable with the more specific type.

See if this works any better for you:

```
Circle *circle= new Circle(3);
circle->get_radius();
```